# What type of collection should be returned from EFCore 3.1 in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-8.0

I'm writing ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and I caught myself being confused... if I use the right type to return.

So here is my code (I removed paging for simplicity):

```
public class UserData
{
    public IEnumerable<UserDto> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = _fni.Users.AsNoTracking()
            .OrderBy(row => row.UserName);

        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDto>>(users);
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var users = _userData.GetUsers();

    return Ok(users);
}
```

Users are queried from the database and immediately returned to the API's client. In C# 8 era, what's the best way to return this collection?

- `IEnumerable`
- `List<UserDto>`
- `async Task<List<UserDto>>`
- `IAsyncEnumerable`

EDIT: The question is about what should be returned by EFCore3.1, in the Data Repository in `UserData` class. *Not* from the Controller.

Comment: Return `IActionResult` because it offers the most flexibility such as returning errors and pretty much anything else. With Custom types it is easier to infer the return from the signature but if you needed to return errors, you would use exceptions.

Comment: During the actuall transmission phase, collections are prone to just be flattened/simplified to a plain old array. None of the other collection Types make any Sense for a collection in-transit. They only work for collections in-memory. But as it is usually trival to feed or turn an array into any other collection, you will propably not notice it with a decent host of Automagic code dealing with the Plumbing.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks for the suggestion, but I do return `IActionResult` from my Controller. My question (although the ideally clear, as I can see it now) was about what should EFCore (Data Repository) return. You're not saying that my Data repo should return `IActionResult`, are you?

Comment: Absolutely not. Your repository should return `IEnumerable<T>` if you don't want the clients to add items to the collection. If you do want to allow the collection to be modified, then `List<T>` makes more sense. Return whichever makes the most sense.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I understand that it's costly to convert to `List<T>` and we should only do it if we want to modify the collection. So in single application it make sense to use `IEnumerable`. But we're talking about API and the data flow looks like this: Repo -> Controller -> (convert to json) -> Client app. Isn't "convert to json" as costly as converting to `List` and thus, it doesn't really make a difference if we return `List` or `Enumerable` from the Repo?

Comment: I said nothing about the cost. The signature of the method should reveal its intention and usage. Your repository should not care about the data being converted to XML or JSON etc.

Comment: @CodingYoshi But you said "If you do want to allow the collection to be modified". Isn't conversion to JSON a little bit like modification? Also, if I know the collection will be modified before sending through the wire, should I return `List` or `async List` from the Repo?

Comment: No, conversion to JSON is not modification. Modification would be adding another item or removing an item to the same instance that you returned. Basically if your repository returns an `Ienumerable` you're telling the client, you can use anything from `IEnumerable`. If the client converts that to a `List` and starts adding/removing, it's no longer what you gave the client. It's another `List`. Returning async basically means the work within the repository to fulfill the request may not happen synchronously (a whole new topic).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation from Microsoft regarding return types from Controller. See if that helps you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

Generally **IEnumerable** is a good choice to seal the results before send them to the request owner. Thus you can be sure that the collection did not change during the transmission. (by any mid-level function etc.)

**IAsyncEnumerable** is also a good choice if you are planning to iterate the whole list immediately.

Check this to see various use cases of IAsyncEnumerable: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/

Also, as far as I can understand this code part belongs to a repository. You may need to reconsider using dto mapping inside of a repository. Since the repository pattern only responsible for the management of the data in a lower level, mapping the data to the transfer objects is not a responsibility of the repository pattern. (Breaks the single responsibility rule)

Comment: Hi, have an upvote. Would you mind if I ask a follow-up question here?

Comment: @ycansener Hmm.. you're saying "be sure that the collection did not change during the transmission". But isn't `IEnumerable` converted to `Array`, `List` or something during serialization/converting to `json`?